# Is there an antonym for "advertisement" or "commercial"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, antonyms

Given that it's designed to separate people from their money, a commercial or advertisement almost always focuses on the positive aspects of a product or activity.

Is there an antonym for this? In other words, what would be the word for an informational message which points out the negative qualities or advises people *not* to use/do something?

Comment: ***Propaganda***, maybe.

Comment: In some context propoganda, yes, but what what if the situation is clear and in the notice there are only true scientific facts. Let's say a company tells you not to buy their phones anymore because they're faulty. You can't say it's that phone's commercial and it definitely isn't propoganda.

Comment: Try ***product recall*** in that case.

Comment: Warnings perhaps? Many places have notices warning people not to do things, such as "Do not cross tracks" warnings by train tracks or "Danger! High voltage" warnings by electrical lines.

Comment: **PSA** = *Public Service Announcement*.

Comment: Warning's really close! But it's not always imperative, it could be a simple short video talking about negative sides of someone's character, it's not a commercial and it's not really a warning either. Any other ideas?
Thanks for the answers so far!

Comment: "negative publicity" or "counteradvertising" dissuade consumers from buying a product or service.

Answer (score 1):

I found a word admonition and a verb admonish. Which is almost an exact antonym I believe.

Noun definition: advice with a hint of scolding, a warning not to do something.

Verb definition: to caution, advise, or counsel against something.

So it can be a notice against a person or a product as well I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Use the word ***warning*** or ***alert*** to mean a notice of caution.

When you do something on your computer that the system sees as harmful or unwanted, you often see a warning such as "You are about to do ABC. Are you sure?" In old systems, for example, "Delete * . *" meant erasing all files.  If you meant to do just that, you would continue. If not, you would be thankful the alert gave you a chance to cancel your mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Not an exact antonym, but consider ***recall*** — [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/recall)

> (noun) 5. a public call by a manufacturer for the return of a product that may be defective or contaminated
>   *"The factory has issued a recall of all cars with the defective brakes."*

See also: [*recall notice*](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=%22recall%20notice%22), [*product recall*](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=%22product%20recall%22)